# How to fill this region in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, shading, fill

How to draw this figure in `tikz`

[image]

The two closed curves shown can be any irregular closed curves (they *may* or *may not* look exactly like in the picture); also, the area around the point *x* can be a circle as well. I do not have any idea about how to execute the shading. Any idea would be appreciated. This is what I have got so far (motivated from [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/532128/162028) answer to one of my earlier questions).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[declare function={rrnd(\x)=2.2+0.2*rnd+0.5*cos(2*\x);}]
        \pgfmathsetseed{137}
        \draw [thick] (-4,-3.5) rectangle (5.5,4);
        \draw [thick] plot[smooth cycle,samples at={0,30,...,330}] (\x:{rrnd(\x)});
        \draw [thick, rotate=90, shift={(0,-3)}]  plot[smooth cycle,samples at={0,30,...,330}] (\x:{rrnd(\x)});
        \draw [fill=red, opacity=0.5] (3.5,-1) node[fill=black, circle, inner sep=1pt, label=below:{$ x $}] {} circle (0.75);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**PS:** I also have no idea about how to describe this problem in the title of the question. So if anyone can substantiate that with more searchable specifications, please feel free to do so.

Comment: The shading is not the problem here. It can be done with a simple `\clip` command. What seems to be more difficult is creating the inner dashed area. Do you really want to create this area parallel to the external shape? This was discussed earlier on this website and it can be a pain to do. Maybe simpler by using `spath3` package, from Andrew Stacey.

Comment: @SebGlav, can it not be done by repeating the same function with a `scale` not equal to 1?

Comment: If you want something really parallel, you can't do it like this. If you just want something approximative, maybe. I'll see what I can do.

Comment: @SebGlav, yes, of course, approximative will definitely work. Thanks.